# Creating an AD User that can only access the Network and C Drive

Tags: windows-10, active-directory

I am trying to create a User that can only acccess the Internet and using the installed Office. The User should have no access to printers, network drives or other productive resources.

Does anyone have an idea how i could accomplish that with GPOs or usersettings?

The client is a Windows 10 and the Server is a Windows Server 2019

edit: Changed the heading due to the migration

Comment: This is a pretty basic set up, common to and easily achieved in any AD domain. Based on your question I'd guess you're in school and this is a homework question.

Comment: Its for a production enviroment... I didn't find anything in the microsoft documentation for that usecase. It should only affect one specific user on a shared client.@music2myear

Comment: You're probably thinking about this wrong. You need to think of HOW people are allowed to access a given resource, each resource individually, and then extrapolate how they would NOT be allowed to access the resource (active prevention is always better than simply hiding things), and then put together the various methods into a single solution. You're not trying to solve the WHOLE problem and of course that won't be in Microsoft's documentation. But each step will be, and I guarantee thousands (at least) have had the same question and talked about it online.

Comment: see if below helps you https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app

Comment: Thanks for everyone who contributed. You helped me setting a path to follow.
In the end i created a GPO with only 4 apps allowed